# jQuery Toggle Divs Expand When JavaScript do_PostBack Link Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a new site [TheDigitalScale](http://www.thedigitalscale.com) and I am using jQuery to create a feature list that expands a div when clicked and closes the div with another click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".msg_body").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".msg_head").click(function()
  {
    $(this).toggleClass("msg_head2").next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
  });
});
</script>



<div class="msg_list">
    <p class="msg_head">They Forgot The Buttons</p>
    <div class="msg_body"><p>
    Just kidding. The MXT has nifty touchscreen controls so you never have to worry about buttons getting dirty or broken. 
    </p></div>
    </div>
```

It works fine and all but, I also have a product review link that uses the JavaScript do_PostBack function to expand a review panel.

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$wpm$ShowProduct$ctl07$ReviewLink','')">Review and Rate this item</a>
```

When the review link is clicked, it causes all of the jQuery divs to expand.

When I set enablepartialrendering to false and it "fixes" the problem but when the review link is clicked it takes the user to the top of the page and expands the review panel rather than just expanding the review panel and keeping the user in the right spot.

I hope I explained this well enough; I am very new to jQuery, JavaScript and AJAX.

Regards,
Shala

**EDIT:**

I suppose I didn't really ask a question so...

What can I change to make the review link expand the review panel and keep the user in the area without also expanding every one of the jQuery divs?

Here is a link to a product page: [MBSC-55](http://www.thedigitalscale.com/My-Weigh-MBSC-55-Digital-Baby-Scale-P7C12.aspx)

Comment: I think __doPostBack is a .net thing, probably should have included that in the tags for the question.  Is there a page that is accessible that we can see what is happening?

Comment: Hi kingjiv, thank you for the tag suggestion. The site is using ASP.net and AJAX. Here is a product page that has the probem: [link](http://www.thedigitalscale.com/My-Weigh-MBSC-55-Digital-Baby-Scale-P7C12.aspx). Right now I have it setup with enablepartialrendering="true" so the divs will expand when the "Review and Rate this item" link is clicked.

Comment: is this wrapped in an updatepanel? if so id check that the update panel is not returning the expander items too that would replace the contents of the div, breaking your code...

Comment: @ Shala have you tried changing:  `$(".msg_head").click(function()` to  `$(".msg_head").bind('click', function()` ? Or even adding a function to the review like `$('a.review').live('click', function(prev){ prev.preventDefault(); });` ... or something like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have nested updatepanels. Try setting the [UpdateMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) of the parent panel to `Conditional` to prevent the child updatepanel from triggering the parent updatepanel.

Comment: Looks like kingjiv's answer fixed the problem. I do want to thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: You're welcome. Note though: You are probably taking a performance hit by re-rendering the content of the parent updatepanel. As kingjiv mentioned in his answer, it would probably be best if you used my method to eliminate the unnecessary HTML in the first place.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely take a look at the link you provided and give it a try. I'm hesitant to do so as I am very new to this and am afraid our site might go down in flames. Thank you again.

Comment: Okay, I went in and found the UpdatePanel changed it to conditional and now everything is peachy. Thanks again for the answer, for explaining why it's the best answer and providing a link to the info I needed. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I see what's happening.  When your page loads you execute this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".msg_body").hide();

  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".msg_head").click(function()  {
    $(this).toggleClass("msg_head2").next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
  });
});
```

Now, when .net does the postback it is re-creating those .msg_body and .msg_head elements.  The best solution would be to get .net to not replace those (unless you need them to).

If you need those to re-draw, you can do 2 things.  First, set .msg_body to be hidden in your css, that way they are hidden by default.  Then to handle the click issue, replace your click code with this:

```
  $(".msg_head").live("click", function()  {
    $(this).toggleClass("msg_head2").next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
  });
```

This will cause the click handler to still work for newly added .msg_head items.

Comment: Worked like a charm. You really know you're stuff! Thank you very much for taking the time to take a look and provide an answer.